# Oracle sysdate format change from dd/mm/yy to ddmmyy

Tags: sql, oracle

The data length in our production DB, DATE data type, is 7, the sysdate function return 8 characters (dd/mm/yy) .
Is there any way to eliminate '/' and only populate 'ddmmyy'.

Tried the below but no luck.

```
  INSERT INTO TESTER(tablename,columnname,defaultdate,prime_number) VALUES ('tabL7845','field894',REPLACE(SYSDATE,'/',''),105);

  INSERT INTO TESTER(tablename,columnname,defaultdate,prime_number) VALUES ('ta68888','fiG987',TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MMDDYY'),180);

  INSERT INTO TESTER(tablename,columnname,defaultdate,prime_number) VALUES ('tab345','field464',TRIM(BOTH '/' FROM SYSDATE),65);
```

Row is getting inserted but in table i could find the same sysdate format,

```
for eg ) 07/08/20

How can i populate as 070820
```

Trigger code :

```
 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER def_trig 
 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF datedef ON Test 
 REFERENCING OLD AS O NEW AS N 
 FOR EACH ROW 
 DECLARE
   V_DATA_LENGTH NUMBER;
   V_DATA_TYPE VARCHAR2(15);
 BEGIN
 SELECT DATA_LENGTH,DATA_TYPE 
 INTO V_DATA_LENGTH,V_DATA_TYPE 
 FROM all_tab_columns 
 WHERE table_name = :n.tablename 
 AND column_name =:n.columnname
 IF INSERTING THEN
        IF v_data_type = 'DATE' THEN
            IF length(:n.datedef) > V_DATA_LENGTH THEN
                RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'DATE FIELD LENGTH IS MORE THAN THE CORESPONDING COLUMN DATA LENGTH');
            END IF;
        ELSE
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSERT IS SUCCESSFUL');
        END IF;
END if;
END;
/
```

Comment: You don't insert dates "formatted", you format them when you **display** them.

Comment: The display format and the internal binary structure are two different things. There is no `/` stored in a date.

Comment: Hi i have a following trigger condition that does not allow insert when data_length is greater than inserted values. (Trigger code attached. ) . I am unable to insert since sysdate(8) > 7 . Any other workarounds for this?

Comment: Your requirement **makes no sense**. Dates have an internal structure with a fixed length; the format of the input date string has **no impact** on the storage space taken.

Answer (score 1):

Dates in Oracle do not have any internal sort of text formatting; they are stored as binary.  If you want to *view* a `SYSDATE` value in a certain text format, then use `TO_CHAR` with the appropriate format mask:

```
INSERT INTO TESTER (tablename, columnname, defaultdate, prime_number)
VALUES ('ta68888', 'fiG987', sysdate, 180);   -- just insert plain SYSDATE here

SELECT
    tablename,
    columnname,
    TO_CHAR(defaultdate, 'DDMMYY'),           -- then view SYSDATE however you want
    prime_number
FROM TESTER;
```

Here is the output from the above query:

[image: screen capture from demo below]

### Demo

Comment: since the 'defaultdate' data_length is itself is only '7' , is there any other way i can insert current date with only 7 character ?

Comment: @ssrad **No**.  Do _not_ store dates as text, use a proper date column.

Answer (score 0):

Internally dates are stored as a structure of 7 1byte integers, that's where the length 7 comes from.  From that structure any valid format can be displayed **without any data change**. To see this select the same column with multiple formats. For example:

```
alter session st nls_date_format = 'hh24:mi:ss  dd-Mon-yyyy';
select defaultdate 
  from teaster  
 where defaultdate is not null 
   and row_num<2;

alter session set nls_date_format = 'Dy dd-Mon-yyyy @ hh24:mi:ss' ;
select defaultdate 
  from teaster  
 where defaultdate is not null 
   and row_num<2;
```

To get a glimpse at the internal format run:

```
select defaultdate, dump(defaultdate) from teaster;
```

This will show you the default date (interpreted as directed by  nls_date_format) and a glimpse of the internal structure.